# SF colony novel, most likely from before 1972

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, space-colonization

A librarian friend received the following query about a novel a customer read long ago. I hope somebody can help.

> The situation is that it can be foreseen that the Earth will collapse/break down — for whatever reason I do not remember — perhaps pollution. To prevent this from causing the annihilation of humanity, a series of spacecraft are being built to search for planets in the galaxy where humans can survive. As the journeys are long, there are not carrying people, but a kind of fetuses that will be activated upon arrival at a suitable planet. However, these new people are cultureless and for them to find out about working together and building communities, the ships carry ideas for this as well. Different spaceships have different social models. The spaceship the narrative follows has a community software that is inspired by ancient Greek democracy where people for the governing bodies and administration are selected by lot (this is correct - the conversations and polls on the Agora are of limited importance). What happens next I can't remember. As to when the story is from, I don't know, but I think I read it before 1972.

Comment: Somebody on another forum has suggested Clarke's *The Songs of Distant Earth*, which seems to fit well apart from the timeframe. Can anybody confirm if it features representation by lots? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Songs_of_Distant_Earth?fbclid=IwAR0_A9qVu_7dtYA8yePqV8yoFqWrhRjeo8-LawinlRgrxFpsNXk8jZ_t6CI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is in fact almost definitely [*The Songs of Distant Earth*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1164) (1986) by Arthur C. Clarke.

Earth is threatened not by human effects, but by the imminent death of the Sun, predicted to die in under 2000 years.

> No one heard the first tolling of Earth's funeral bell - not even the scientists who made the fatal discovery, far underground, in an abandoned Colorado gold mine.
> It was a daring experiment, quite inconceivable before the mid-twentieth century. Once the neutrino had been detected, it was quickly realized that mankind had a new window on the universe. Something so penetrating that it passed through a planet as easily as light through a sheet of glass could be used to look into the hearts of suns.

> Especially the Sun. Astronomers were confident that they understood the reactions powering the solar furnace, upon which all life on Earth ultimately depended. At the enormous pressures and temperatures at the Sun's core, hydrogen was fused to helium, in a series of reactions that liberated vast amounts of energy. And, as an incidental by-product, neutrinos.

> Finding the trillions of tons of matter in their way no more obstacle than a wisp of smoke, those solar neutrinos raced up from their birthplace at the velocity of light. Just two seconds later they emerged into space, and spread outward across the universe. However many stars and planets they encountered, most of them would still have evaded capture by the insubstantial ghost of 'solid' matter when Time itself came to an end.

> Eight minutes after they had left the Sun, a tiny fraction of the solar torrent swept through the Earth - and an even smaller fraction was intercepted by the scientists in Colorado. They had buried their equipment more than a kilometre underground so that all the less penetrating radiations would be filtered out and they could trap the rare, genuine messengers from the heart of the Sun. By counting the captured neutrinos, they hoped to study in detail conditions at a spot that, as any philosopher could easily prove, was forever barred from human knowledge or observation.

> The experiment worked; solar neutrinos were detected. But there were far too few of them. There should have been three or four times as many as the massive instrumentation had succeeded in capturing.

Ships are built carrying embryos:

> The first seedships were primitive, yet even so they stretched technology to the limit. With the propulsion systems available by 2500, they could reach the nearest planetary system in two hundred years, carrying their precious burden of frozen embryos.

> But that was the least of their tasks. They also had to carry the automatic equipment that would revive and rear these potential humans, and teach them how to survive in an unknown but probably hostile environment. It would be useless - indeed, cruel - to decant naked, ignorant children on to worlds as unfriendly as the Sahara or the Antarctic. They had to be educated, given tools, shown how to locate and use local resources. After it had landed and the seedship became a Mother Ship, it might have to cherish its brood for generations.

Government roles on Thalassa are filled by lottery:

> The President of Thalassa had been in office for only two months and was still unreconciled to his misfortune. But there was nothing he could do about it, except to make the best of a bad job for the three years it would last. Certainly it was no use demanding a recount; the selection program, which involved the generation and interleaving of thousand-digit random numbers, was the nearest thing to pure chance that human ingenuity could devise.

> There were exactly five ways to avoid the danger of being dragged into the Presidential Palace (twenty rooms, one large enough to hold almost a hundred guests). You could be under thirty or over seventy; you could be incurably ill; you could be mentally defective; or you could have committed a grave crime. The only option really open to President Edgar Farradine was the last, and he had given it serious thought.

> Yet he had to admit that, despite the personal inconvenience it had caused him, this was probably the best form of government that mankind had ever devised. The mother planet had taken some ten thousand years to perfect it, by trial and often hideous error.

> As soon as the entire adult population had been educated to the limits of its intellectual ability (and sometimes, alas, beyond) genuine democracy became possible. The final step required the development of instantaneous personal communications, linked with central computers. According to the historians, the first true democracy on Earth was established in the (Terran) year 2011, in a country called New Zealand.

> Thereafter, selecting a head of state was relatively unimportant. Once it was universally accepted that anyone who deliberately aimed at the job should automatically be disqualified, almost any system would serve equally well, and a lottery was the simplest procedure.

Comment: The only part I haven't found is different colonies being set up with different forms of government.

Comment: Note that *Songs* is based on a 1958 short story of the same name (*Worlds of IF*, June 1958) but I reviewed that and it doesn't have any of these details, and in fact the colonization ships had live crews and Earth still exists.